# "Couldn't find User without an ID" accessing related model

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, database, hash

Updated issue:

I am trying to access an id for an instance of a class and use it to look up that instance. Here is the context:

```
  <% @affinity.each do |a| %>
    <tr>
      <td><%= a.user_A_id %></td>
      <td><%= User.find(a.user_A_id).nickname %></td>
      <td><%= a.user_B_id %></td>
      <td><%= User.find(a.user_B_id).nickname %></td>
      ...
```

Each `affinity` has a variable called `User_A_id` and `User_B_id`, which represent the IDs of Users A and B. I want to use these ids to be able to access the instances of User A and User B, and subsequently the `nickname` of each. How can I do this?

I currently get this error:

```
Couldn't find User without an ID
```

Thanks!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you have the correct relations defined, you can access those users directly:

```
<%= a.user_A.nickname %>
```

And BTW, you shouldn't have to convert those ids to symbols to make that code work, and you could have used `User.find(a.user_A_id)` since `where` returns an array and `find` returns the object if it was found.

Comment: I made these edits. Now I get this error:
'Couldn't find User without an ID'

Comment: Are you sure the field `user_A_id` contains a value? And you should try my first suggestion and call the related object as `a.user_A.nickname`.

Comment: Thank you! This was the problem.